# elasticsearch - there is no setup-passwords bin in x-pack directory

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I use

`brew install elasticsearch`

and

`elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack`

The `x-pack` path is `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.2.4/libexec/plugins/x-pack`

But, there is no `setup-passwords` in this path

```
☁  ~  ls /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.2.4/libexec/plugins/x-pack
meta-plugin-descriptor.properties x-pack-graph                      x-pack-monitoring                 x-pack-watcher
x-pack-core                       x-pack-logstash                   x-pack-security
x-pack-deprecation                x-pack-ml                         x-pack-upgrade
```

I want to generate default passwords using

`bin/x-pack/setup-passwords auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path for `setup-passwords` command is:

`/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.2.4/libexec/bin/x-pack/setup-passwords`